# using bass library to decode mp3 file

Tags: c#, bass

How can i convert Mp3 file to custom sample data using bass library in C# ? 
custom means i want result in a certain properties for example mono and 5000hz! 
i try this code before but it does not works!

> public float[] ReadMonoFromFile(string filename, int samplerate, 
>                  int milliseconds, int startmillisecond) {
>
> ```
> int totalmilliseconds = 
>     milliseconds <= 0 ? Int32.MaxValue : milliseconds + startmillisecond;
> float[] data = null;
> //create streams for re-sampling
> int stream = Bass.BASS_StreamCreateFile(filename, 0, 0, 
>     BASSFlag.BASS_STREAM_DECODE | BASSFlag.BASS_SAMPLE_MONO | 
>     BASSFlag.BASS_SAMPLE_FLOAT); //Decode the stream
> if (stream == 0)
>     throw new Exception(Bass.BASS_ErrorGetCode().ToString());
> int mixerStream = BassMix.BASS_Mixer_StreamCreate(samplerate, 1, 
>     BASSFlag.BASS_STREAM_DECODE | BASSFlag.BASS_SAMPLE_MONO | 
>     BASSFlag.BASS_SAMPLE_FLOAT);
> if (mixerStream == 0)
>     throw new Exception(Bass.BASS_ErrorGetCode().ToString());
> if (BassMix.BASS_Mixer_StreamAddChannel(mixerStream, stream, BASSFlag.BASS_MIXER_FILTER))
> {
>     int bufferSize = samplerate * 10 * 4; /*read 10 seconds at each iteration*/
>     float[] buffer = new float[bufferSize];
>     List<float[]> chunks = new List<float[]>();
>     int size = 0;
>     while ((float) (size)/samplerate*1000 < totalmilliseconds)
>     {
>         //get re-sampled/mono data
>         int bytesRead = Bass.BASS_ChannelGetData(mixerStream, buffer, bufferSize);
>         if (bytesRead == 0) 
>             break;
>         float[] chunk = new float[bytesRead/4]; //each float contains 4 bytes
>         Array.Copy(buffer, chunk, bytesRead/4);
>         chunks.Add(chunk);
>         size += bytesRead/4; //size of the data
>     }
>
>     if ((float) (size)/samplerate*1000 < (milliseconds + startmillisecond))
>         return null; /*not enough samples to return the requested data*/
>     int start = (int) ((float) startmillisecond*samplerate/1000);
>     int end = (milliseconds <= 0) ? size : 
>        (int) ((float) (startmillisecond + milliseconds)*samplerate/1000);
>     data = new float[size];
>     int index = 0;
>     /*Concatenate*/
>     foreach (float[] chunk in chunks)
>     {
>         Array.Copy(chunk, 0, data, index, chunk.Length);
>         index += chunk.Length;
>     }
>     /*Select specific part of the song*/
>     if (start != 0 || end != size)
>     {
>         float[] temp = new float[end - start];
>         Array.Copy(data, start, temp, 0, end - start);
>         data = temp;
>     }
> }
> else
>     throw new Exception(Bass.BASS_ErrorGetCode().ToString());
> return data; }
> ```

i called  this function like this:

> float[] pcm = ReadMonoFromFile(Path.GetFullPath("1.mp3"), 0, 0, 0);

but in throws this exception :The type initializer for 'Un4seen.Bass.Bass' threw an exception.

Comment: I guarantee it said more than 'threw an exception'

Answer (score 1):

Add Bass.dll to your bin folder.